# How to filter array of objects on date

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects I need to filter through and return only the objects closest to today. The issue I'm having is that it's returning the June date and not the one in May. here's the code I'm using:

```
const findClosest = (data, accessor, target = Date.now()) =>
  data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const a = Math.abs(accessor(curr).getTime() - target);
    const b = Math.abs(accessor(prev).getTime() - target);
    return a - b < 0 ? curr : prev;
  });

const getClosestFromDate = (array, key, date) => {
  let arr = array.filter((e) => e[key] == date);
  return arr;
};

const sampleData = [{
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-06-23T00:00:00",
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-06-23T00:00:00",
  },
  {
    "is_swappable": true,
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-06-23T00:00:00",
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-06-23T00:00:00",
  },
  {
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-05-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-07-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-05-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-05-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
  {
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-07-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
];

const processDateString = (dateString) => {
  let date = new Date(dateString);
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  let month = date.getMonth();
  console.log(date.toString());
  return new Date(year, month + 1, date);
};

const closest = findClosest(sampleData, ({
  next_charge_scheduled_at
}) => processDateString(next_charge_scheduled_at), "2022-05-10T03:03:42");

console.log(closest.next_charge_scheduled_at);

console.log(getClosestFromDate(sampleData, "next_charge_scheduled_at", closest.next_charge_scheduled_at));
```

I got this code from one of the other questions, but for some reason even after trying multiple times to add or subtract from the month variable, I am unable to return the correct date. I'd really appreciate help on this.

Comment: How do you call it the closest dates to today? dates in the current month? I think your question is not clear enough

Comment: *returning the June date and not the one in May*  =>  `month + 1` may be the reason.

Comment: `return new Date(year, month + 1, date);`  => "date" appears to be a `Date` object, not a date-of-the-month.

Comment: *I got this code from one of the other questions*  => "As ye copy so shall ye reap." Sorry, I couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 2):

You were making life too hard for yourself:

(I revised my answer after reading OP's latest comment.)

The const `acc` is a utility `function(obj)` that will grab the `next_charge_scheduled_at` property of the `obj`, turn it into a `date` object and then return its `.getTime()` value.

`findClosest(sampleData,acc)` returns a single object of the given `sampleData` array closest to the target time (`Date.now()`). I then store the `.getTime()`value of this element in the constant `closest` and use it again to filter through the original input array:

```js
const sampleData = [{
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-06-23T00:00:00",
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-06-23T00:00:00",
  },
  {
    "is_swappable": true,
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-06-23T00:00:00",
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-06-23T00:00:00",
  },
  {
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-05-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-07-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-05-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
  {
    "max_retries_reached": 0,
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-05-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
  {
    "next_charge_scheduled_at": "2022-07-23T00:00:00",
    "order_day_of_month": null,
  },
];
const 
 findClosest = (data, accessor, target = Date.now()) =>
  data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const a = Math.abs(accessor(curr) - target);
    const b = Math.abs(accessor(prev) - target);
    return a - b < 0 ? curr : prev;
 }),
 acc=obj=>new Date(obj.next_charge_scheduled_at).getTime(),
 closest=acc(findClosest(sampleData,acc));
 
console.log(sampleData.filter(d=>acc(d)===closest));
```

The following version is even shorter and avoids the repeated calcuation of `Date` objects:

```
function getClosest(arr){
  const trg=Date.now() 
   times=sampleData.map((d,i)=>[new Date(d.next_charge_scheduled_at).getTime(),i]),
   closest=times.reduce((p,c) => Math.abs(c[0]-trg) < Math.abs(p[0]-trg) ? c : p)[0];
  return times.reduce((a,[t,i])=>(t==closest&&a.push(arr[i]),a),[]);
}
```

`getClosest()` uses a temporary array `times` to store the calculated `.getTime()` value and the index `i` for each object. After finding the closest time to `Date.now()` the `times` array is then `-reduce()`d in order to compile the results from the original input array `arr`.

Comment: Thank you so much! A lot of insight here. I used the additional filter() function to return all of the items from my array of objects that matches that date. Is there a better way to do this following your example?

Comment: OK, I changed my answer - now you get _all_ elements that have the closest time stamp to the given target value.